# Make my awk shell script more efficient (parsing python)

Tags: python, bash, shell, awk

I was recently tasked with auditing all of the python modules my team uses across our entire production code repository.

I came up with the following:

```
find ~/svn/ -name *.py 
| xargs grep -hn "^import\|^from"
| awk -F ":" '{print $2}' 
| awk '{if (/from/) print $2; else {$1 = ""; print $0} }' 
| sed 's/,\| /\n/g' 
| sort 
| uniq > /tmp/pythonpkgs.txt
```

In sequence, it

- Finds all the python files
- Of those, greps for lines beginning with `import` or `from`
- splits on the `:` character and uses what follows, so the file name and the number of the output aren't included
- if the line is of the form `from foo import bar`, print `foo`, else if it's of form `import foo` print `foo`
- replace commas and spaces with line breaks, for lines like `import a, b, c`
- sort output and take uniques

I hacked this together on my own, but I imagine it could be better. How would you do it? Consolidate the `awk`s?

Comment: Show the an example of the data you are parsing, but from the looks of it everything except the find can be done in a single awk script

Comment: Just a note that this will fail for an import that is spread across multiple lines; but perhaps that's non-existent in the code. I assume you've already safely ran the above code.

Comment: @JID I can post an example if you want, but it's all python scripts of various types in which I want to detect things like `pygal.style` within the string `from pygal.style import NeonStyle` , or `time` from within `import time`.

@Evert - you're right. I did do a manual audit on a sample and I'm confident that I don't need to worry about that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty clever setup to start with, but there are a couple places where it can be cleaned up:

```
1: find ~/svn/ -name *.py 
2: | xargs grep -hn "^import\|^from"
3: | awk -F ":" '{print $2}' 
4: | awk '{if (/from/) print $2; else {$1 = ""; print $0} }' 
5: | sed 's/,\| /\n/g' 
6: | sort 
7: | uniq > /tmp/pythonpkgs.txt
```

Line 3: You don't need the first awk split/print -- just don't include `-n` on the grep so that you don't include the line number in the output.

```
time find ./<<my_large_project>> -name *.py 
| xargs grep -hn "^import\|^from" 
| awk '{if (/from/) print $2; else {$1 = ""; print $0} }' 
| sed 's/,\| /\n/g' 
| sort 
| uniq
~~snip~~
real    0m0.492s
user    0m0.208s
sys     0m0.116s
```

Lines 6-7, and 4-5: If you have a lot of duplicate lines, you can speed up your execution by `sort`ing and `uniq`-ing before running your `awk` and `sed`

```
time find ./<<my_large_project>> -name *.py 
| xargs grep -hn "^import\|^from" 
| sort 
| uniq 
| awk '{if (/from/) print $2; else {$1 = ""; print $0} }' 
| sed 's/,\| /\n/g'
~~snip~~
real    0m0.464s
user    0m0.224s
sys     0m0.140s
```

Note that this will miss multiple line imports as described in [PEP 0328](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/).  Support for these imports would make your regex search relatively non-trivial as you would have to look for optional parenthesis and make note of prior whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

grepping source code for specific constructs is pretty fragile, there are many situations where it may fail. Consider, for example:

```
import foo ; print 123
```

or

```
import foo, \
   bar
```

or

```
 str = '''
 import foo
 '''
```

etc.

If you're interested in a more robust approach, this is how you can reliably parse out imported names using the python's own compiler:

```
import ast

def list_imports(source):
    for node in ast.walk(ast.parse(source)):
        if isinstance(node, ast.Import):
            for name in node.names:
                yield name.name
        if isinstance(node, ast.ImportFrom):
            yield node.module
```

Usage:

```
 for name in sorted(set(list_imports(some_source))):
     print name
```

Comment: I assumed by the `~/svn` that he's looking for both in-use and not-in-use code. I'd agree that this is the most "correct" approach though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my consolidated awk:

```
/^[ \t]*import .* as/  {
    sub("^[ \t]+","");          # remove leading whitespace
    sub("[ \t]*#.*","");        # remove comments
    print $2;
    next;
}
/^[ \t]*from (.*) import/ {
    sub("^[ \t]+","");          # remove leading whitespace
    sub("[ \t]*#.*","");        # remove comments
    print $2;
    next;
}
/^[ \t]*import (.*)/  {
    sub("^[ \t]+","");          # remove leading whitespace
    sub("[ \t]*#.*","");        # remove comments
    split(substr($0,7),a,",");  # split on commas
    for (i=1;i<=length(a);i++) {
        gsub("[ \t]+","",a[i]); # trim whitespace
        print a[i];
    }
    next;
}
```

Call with:

```
find . -name '*.py' -exec awk -f scan.awk {} \; | sort | uniq
```

As noted, it doesn't take care of a few potential cases, such as lines joined with ';' or split with '\', or grouped with '()', but it would cover the majority of Python code.